# mapping/xslt challenge - grouping, key

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary, biztalk

We have a bit tricky mapping requirements. I am working on converting an incoming xml from one form to another in BizTalk application using BizTalk mapper. The solution can be done using XSLT or built in BizTalk functoids.

Source schema looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://BizTalkTestProject.SourceSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://BizTalkTestProject.SourceSchema">
    <xs:element name="Coverages">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Coverage" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="BillingChargeType" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ASLCode" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="EffectiveDate" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="DeltaAmount" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Destination schema looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://BizTalkTestProject.DestinationSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://BizTalkTestProject.DestinationSchema">
    <xs:element name="Categories" type="CategoriesType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CategoriesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Premium" type="CommonElementsType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Tax" type="CommonElementsType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Fee" type="CommonElementsType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CommonElementsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CategoryDetail" type="CategoryDetailType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CategoryDetailType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="AnnualStatementLine" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="ChangeEffectiveDate" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample incoming xml data:

```
    <ns0:Coverages xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalkTestProject.SourceSchema">
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 2</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 2</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2002-02-02</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>22.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 1</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 1</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2001-01-01</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>11.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 1</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 2</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2001-01-01</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>121.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 1</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 1</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2002-02-02</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>112.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 3</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 3</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2003-03-03</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>33.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>premium</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 1</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>premium ASLCode 1</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2001-01-01</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>5.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>tax</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>tax BillingChargeType 4</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>tax ASLCode 4</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2004-04-04</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>44.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>tax</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>tax BillingChargeType 5</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>tax ASLCode 5</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2005-05-05</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>55.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage>
        <Category>fee</Category>
        <BillingChargeType>fee BillingChargeType 6</BillingChargeType>
        <ASLCode>fee ASLCode 6</ASLCode>
        <EffectiveDate>2006-06-06</EffectiveDate>
        <DeltaAmount>66.00</DeltaAmount>
    </Coverage>
</ns0:Coverages>
```

Expected output xml should looks like this:

```
    <ns0:Categories xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalkTestProject.DestinationSchema">
    <Premium>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>premium BillingChargeType 2</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>premium ASLCode 2</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>22.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2002-02-02</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>premium BillingChargeType 1</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>premium ASLCode 1</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>16.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2001-01-01</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>premium BillingChargeType 1</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>premium ASLCode 2</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>121.11</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2001-01-01</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>premium BillingChargeType 1</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>premium ASLCode 1</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>112.22</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2002-02-02</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>premium BillingChargeType 3</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>premium ASLCode 3</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>33.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2003-03-03</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
    </Premium>
    <Tax>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>tax BillingChargeType 4</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>tax ASLCode 4</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>44.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2004-04-04</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>tax BillingChargeType 5</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>tax ASLCode 5</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>55.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2005-05-05</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
    </Tax>
    <Fee>
        <CategoryDetail>
            <Type>fee BillingChargeType 6</Type>
            <AnnualStatementLine>fee ASLCode 6</AnnualStatementLine>
            <Amount>66.00</Amount>
            <ChangeEffectiveDate>2006-06-06</ChangeEffectiveDate>
        </CategoryDetail>
    </Fee>
</ns0:Categories>
```

The mapping requirements are:
1. If Category element from source xml has value “Premium” then it should get mapped to destination under Categories/Premium.
2. If Category element from source xml has value “Tax” then it should get mapped to destination under Categories/Tax.
3. If Category element from source xml has value “Fee” then it should get mapped to destination under Categories/Fee.
4. Output should have only distinct record sets by Category, BillingChargeType, ALSCode and EffectiveDate. 
5. Output should have aggregated value of source node “DeltaAmount” in destination node “Amount” by Category, BillingChargeType, ALSCode and EffectiveDate

In sample xml, I have included an aggregation example for “Premium” node eg.

```
<BillingChargeType>premium BillingChargeType 1</BillingChargeType>
<ASLCode>premium ASLCode 1</ASLCode>
<EffectiveDate>2001-01-01</EffectiveDate>
```

There are two Coverage record sets with above 3 nodes. the difference in those two is

```
<DeltaAmount>11.00</DeltaAmount> and <DeltaAmount>5.00</DeltaAmount>
```

In expected output, you will see only one is getting mapped with DeltaAmount node = 16.

I tried mapping in xslt using key, distinct and generate-id with apply-templates and for-each loop but not getting the result as what we want. So I am here to ask for your help. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks for looking in to this and I appreciate for all your help! 
Mukund

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone interested, below is the copy of an answer, I got from some one on other thread.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalkTestProject.SourceSchema">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="group" match="/ns0:Coverages/Coverage" use="concat(BillingChargeType,Category,ASLCode,EffectiveDate)"/>  
   <xsl:template match="/ns0:Coverages">
     <ns0:Categories xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalkTestProject.DestinationSchema">      
       <xsl:for-each select="Coverage[count(. | key('group', concat(BillingChargeType, Category,ASLCode,EffectiveDate))[1]) = 1]">
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="./Category ='premium'">
               <ns0:Premium>
                 <ns0:CategoryDetail>
                   <Type>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./BillingChargeType"/>
                   </Type>
                   <AnnualStatementLine>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./ASLCode"/>
                   </AnnualStatementLine>
                   <Amount>
                     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('group', concat(BillingChargeType, Category,ASLCode,EffectiveDate))/DeltaAmount),'#,###.00')"/>
                   </Amount>
                   <ChangeEffectiveDate>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./EffectiveDate"/>
                   </ChangeEffectiveDate>

                </ns0:CategoryDetail>
               </ns0:Premium>            
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="./Category ='tax'">            
               <Tax>
                 <CategoryDetail>

                  <Type>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./BillingChargeType"/>
                   </Type>
                   <AnnualStatementLine>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./ASLCode"/>
                   </AnnualStatementLine>
                   <Amount>
                     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('group', concat(BillingChargeType, Category,ASLCode,EffectiveDate))/DeltaAmount),'#,###.00')"/>
                   </Amount>
                   <ChangeEffectiveDate>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./EffectiveDate"/>
                   </ChangeEffectiveDate>

                </CategoryDetail>
               </Tax>

          </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="./Category ='fee'">            
               <fee>
                 <CategoryDetail>

                  <Type>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./BillingChargeType"/>
                   </Type>
                   <AnnualStatementLine>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./ASLCode"/>
                   </AnnualStatementLine>
                   <Amount>
                     <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('group', concat(BillingChargeType, Category,ASLCode,EffectiveDate))/DeltaAmount),'#,###.00')"/>
                   </Amount>
                   <ChangeEffectiveDate>
                     <xsl:value-of select="./EffectiveDate"/>
                   </ChangeEffectiveDate>
                 </CategoryDetail>
               </fee>            
           </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </ns0:Categories>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable in a map, declare a list or array in a script functoid above the method. You can use it to keep track of categories you've mapped already.

The method will return a Boolean which you connect to the output nodes premium and taxes. It takes in the category, checks the collection, if found returns false otherwise it adds it and returns true.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> categories;

public string AddToArray(string cat)
{
    if (categories == null)
    {
        categories = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    }

    if(!categories.Contains(cat))
    {
        categories.Add(cat);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for the reply. Our first preference is to map it without using any inline C# code. The solution you have proposed, I think that is only considering the first 3 requirements. If I misunderstood then please let me know. Thanks, Mukund